# Как сделать блоки более адаптивными?

Tags: html, css, sass

Помогите реализовать адаптивность блоков, чтобы плитки смещались вниз если приложение открыто в телефоне. Я пробовал использовать `media`, но у меня выходила какая-то чушь: то появляется с боку белый фон, то вообще никаких изменений нет.

```css
html, body, section {
 height: 100%;
}
 
body {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
 
div {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

.xop-container {
    display: flex;
}
 
div {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}
 
.xop-left {
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(255, 255, 225, 0.10)), url(http://luxfon.com/images/201203/luxfon.com_6021.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 flex: 1;
 padding: 1rem;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
 
.xop-right {
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(164, 222, 102, 0.10)), url(https://natworld.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C%D1%8F.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 flex: 1;
 padding: 1rem;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.xop-left:hover, .xop-right:hover {
 transform: scale(0.95);
}

.xop-left h1 {
 font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
 font-size: 6rem;
}
 
.xop-right h1 {
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 6rem;
}
 
.xop-button {
 border-radius: 30px;
 color: #ffff;
 background-color: #fcad26;
 padding: 1.5%;
 margin: 0 2%;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 width: 170px;
}
 
.xop-button:hover {
 background: #fcc567;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <section class="xop-container">
    <div class="xop-left">
      <article>
        <h1>Главная</h1><a class="xop-button">Посмотреть</a>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="xop-right">
      <article>
        <h1>Контакты</h1><a class="xop-button">Посмотреть</a>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: я не увидел meta viewport , он есть в разметке ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body,
section {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.xop-left {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(255, 255, 225, 0.10)), url(http://luxfon.com/images/201203/luxfon.com_6021.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.xop-right {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), rgba(164, 222, 102, 0.10)), url(https://natworld.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C%D1%8F.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


/*-----New styles-----*/

.xop-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.xop-left,
.xop-right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .xop-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .xop-right,
  .xop-left {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/*------------------------------------*/

.xop-left:hover,
.xop-right:hover {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

.xop-left h1 {
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.xop-right h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.xop-button {
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #fcad26;
  padding: 1.5%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 170px;
}

.xop-button:hover {
  background: #fcc567;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="xop-container">
  <div class="xop-left">
    <article>
      <h1>Главная</h1><a class="xop-button">Посмотреть</a>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="xop-right">
    <article>
      <h1>Контакты</h1><a class="xop-button">Посмотреть</a>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```